# Jittery movement with falling object moving back and forth horizontally

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I've got a falling object, which i want to move back and forth horizontally while falling.

While i've manage to do this, i'm getting a jittery movement while this happens. When the object falls without horizontal movement, theres no jittery movement.This is also the case if the object just moves horizontally without falling.

I'm currently using rigidbody2d.velocity to move it horizontally and have tried using transform.position and translate but didn't see any difference in smoother movement.

[Jittery Movement GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYTF4.gif)

So clearly theres an issue with combine the two movements together, but i can't work out how to remedy this in order to make it a smooth movement.

[Object Inspector Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lr6JB.png)

Here's the object code for it's movement:

```
public float verticalSpeed = 7f;

private Rigidbody2D object_RB;

private int moveHorizontal;
private int horizontalSpeed;

void Start()
{
    object_RB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    moveHorizontal = Random.Range(1, 3);
    horizontalSpeed = Random.Range(4, 7);
}

void Update()
{
    if (transform.position.y <= -10f)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    if (transform.position.x < -1.7f)
    {
        moveHorizontal = 1;
    }
    else if (transform.position.x > 1.7f)
    {
        moveHorizontal = 2;
    }

    transform.position -= transform.up * Time.deltaTime * verticalSpeed;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (moveHorizontal == 1)
    {
        object_RB.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalSpeed, 0);
    }
    else if (moveHorizontal == 2)
    {
        object_RB.velocity = new Vector2(-horizontalSpeed, 0);
    }
}
```

I'm stuck with this and would appreciate some input to fix this movement.

EDIT - I've tried setting the Interpolate property of the rigidbody to Interpolate or Extrapolate and had no luck. If i set it to Interpolate, the horizontal movement slows down drastically, to a point where it doesn't seem like its moving horizontally at all. Changing it to Extrapolate actually increases the jittery effect.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Interpolate` property of the rigidbody to `Interpolate` or `Extrapolate`?

Comment: @AspectOfTheNoob

Yes i have, forgot to mention that, sorry. 

If i set it to Interpolate, the horizontal movement slows down drastically, to a point where it doesn't seem like its moving horizontally at all.

Changing it to Extrapolate actually increases the jittery effect.

Comment: `transform.position -= transform.up * Time.deltaTime * verticalSpeed;` That cannot work. If you attach a Rigidbody to an object, you should move the object using the Rigidbody's API. Don't use Transform and Rigidbody to move an object at the same time. Use one or the other.

Comment: Ah cheers. I didn't know about using Rigidbody & Transform together.

Managed to get this fixed by changing the transform movement to a Rigidbody one and enabling Interpolate.

Thanks again for your help.